# ASP.NET configuration generate .mdf for SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I use Visual Studio 2012, my question is: when I clicked on `Project->ASP.net configuration`, can I get `aspnetdb.mdf` file for SQL Server 2008 Express, because hostings in croatia doesn't support SQL Server 2012? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify the web.config file properly and put the connection string to use an existing 2008 database for pas.net configuration.